# как перебрать все файлы в папке и записать их имена в список?

Tags: python

Подскажите, с помощью какого модуля можно перебрать все файлы в папке и сохранить названия этих файлов в списке? Или же есть готовые скрипты под такую задачу? С помощью Python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой `os`:

```
import os
folder_path = 'путь_к_папке'
file_names = []
for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)):
        file_names.append(file_name)
print(file_names)
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, что скрипт считывает имена файлов, но игнорирует папки?

Comment: Хм, да, странно

Comment: @SasambaDio да, все верно, `.isfile()` тут происходит проверка, является ли элемент файлом

Comment: Ааа! вот оно что.

Answer (score 0):

Также это можно сделать с помощью функции `os.scandir()`:

```py
import os

folder_path = 'путь_к_папке'
file_names = []

for entry in os.scandir(folder_path):
    if entry.is_file():
        file_names.append(entry.name)
```

UPD: По умолчанию если ничего не передать этой функции, то каталогом для перебора будет текущий.

Подробнее в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir).